# ApplicationInsights and add SOAP service reference

Tags: visual-studio, soap, azure-application-insights

When I updates a SOAP service reference in my Visual Studio 2015 project and build I get the following warning:

```
Warning     Custom tool warning: Could not load type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.ITelemetryProcessor' from assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=1.2.0.5639, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. ProjectName C:\Projects\SolutionName\ProjectName\Service References\ServiceReference\Reference.svcmap   1
```

I have introduced ApplicationInsights to my project since the service reference was created.

Any ideas to fix or debug this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Open Nuget package manager and update the projects in your solution to reference latest stable version of ApplicationInsights: v.2.1. ITelemetryProcessor was introduced in version 2.0, that's why version 1.2 doesn't have this type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not reference ApplicationInsights 1.2 from any of my projects. I reference ApplicationInsights 2.0. I guess the error is from the custom tool that generate the service proxy. Upgrading does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today, and after updating all the packages I had no luck.

My program was running one moment, and the next moment, it suddenly stopped! This had me thinking a bit and I basically undid all my changes until I got it to its previous working state. I started adding the code I needed piece by piece, and eventually found that my problem was with one of the classes I had defined afterwards. My class was defined as

```
public class DriverDetailsItem
{
    private string itemValue;
    public DriverDetailsItem(string itemValue)
    {
        ItemValue = itemValue;
    }

    public string ItemValue { get => itemValue; set => itemValue = value; }
}
```

As soon as I added this class, my program broke. There wasn't a lot to change in this class, except for the way the property getters and setters were used. It turned out that my problem got fixed by changing my getters and setters!

When I changed my class to this:

```
public class DriverDetailsItem
{
    public DriverDetailsItem(string itemValue)
    {
        ItemValue = itemValue;
    }

    public string ItemValue { get ; set; }
}
```

It suddenly worked! I do not know why this caused the problem, I just know this fixed it for me.